# How to Remove a Word from Dictionary of Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dictionary

I added the word `somehting` (or similar) by accident to Dictionary of OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 in Google Chrome > 2nd click. 
I would like to remove it from there. 
I go to Dictionary but I cannot find by the Search tool, etc only `someh` and no success. 
So I should be able to find recently added words or user words.

---

How can remove a recently added word in Dictionary of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On macOS Chrome 60, settings do not let you access the dictionary. Words are actually added in two places where you can manually edit them:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Custom\ Dictionary.txt

~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary
```

Then restart your mac for changes to take effect.

Comment: Are you implicating that the command `chrome://settings/editDictionary` is not working?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 `chrome://settings/editDictionary` is not working in current latest Chrome for macOS Sierra

Comment: I did not find Custom Dictionary.txt, but I did find  `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

### user3439894's proposal

Content in `/Users/masi/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Custom\ Dictionary.txt`

```
somehting
checksum_v1 = 2e0427564c95a02fc68d601104512ebd
```

which you can just delete.

Comment: I don't know if anyone's still monitoring this, but I've deleted the offending word in BOTH of the files mentioned above, and it still won't recognize the misspelling even after restarting both the computer and the browser multiple times. Any suggestions?